# Telethon: получение имени пользователя (first_name) отправившего сообщение

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

Есть проблема с получением имени пользователя. В доках ничего пунтного найдено не было. Советовали использовать такой код:

```py
peer = event.peer_id  
  
if peer.user_id: # Пользователь
    user = await peer.user_info()  
    name = user.first_name
```

Но оно не очень помогло. Ошибка была в том, что возвращается `PeerChannel`, а не `PeerUser`. Возможно решение проблемы в этом и кроется, но пока не получилось найти ничего.